# Update item in dict comprehension python

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

```
words = ['rocky','mahesh','surendra','mahesh','rocky','mahesh','deepak','mahesh','mahesh','mahesh','surendra']

words_count = {}
for word in words:
    words_count[word] = words_count.get(word, 0) + 1

print(words_count)
# Expected Output
# {'rocky': 2, 'mahesh': 6, 'surendra': 2, 'deepak': 1}
```

In this example, I just want to modify value of dict key while dict comprehension

**Note**: not looking other way to find occurrence/count of each key in dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count that without using any import and using as few `.counts` as possible following way:

```
words = ['rocky','mahesh','surendra','mahesh','rocky','mahesh','deepak','mahesh','mahesh','mahesh','surendra']
words_count = {i:words.count(i) for i in set(words)}
print(words_count)  # {'surendra': 2, 'mahesh': 6, 'rocky': 2, 'deepak': 1}
```

Converting `list` to `set` will result in unique values.

Comment: This is slow!! It runs in quadratic time!! That's why I am downvoting

Comment: yes, i like it.... even this might execute same inside counter module.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

words_count = Counter(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

A short, simple, one-liner code:

```
{i:words.count(i) for i in words}
```

Here, we create a dictionary based on the count of the word.
Gives:

```
{'rocky': 2, 'mahesh': 6, 'surendra': 2, 'deepak': 1}
```